# Rewrite url to pretty after redirect to folder - htaccess laravel

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello I have a "protected" folder on my server. In its .htaccess file for conditional redirect of some users I use the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^1\.2\.3\.4*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/special 
RewriteRule ^$ /special [R,NE,NC]
```

In the /special folder I have a .htaccess file with the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

The application in the folder will be laravel based so my content will have to be served from index.php file residing in  `/special/laravel/public/index.php`

I want the URL to look like /special/.

What rules should I put and where for this to happen?

This is a follow up to my previous question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487012/redirecting-specific-ip-to-special-content-htaccess-vs-php

Comment: Just to clarify, are you wanting to know how to get a request for `/special/index.php` to actually load `/special/laravel/public/index.php` or am I totally off?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want, given the already existing rules for redirecting.

Comment: Okay. The way I personally handle it is I always have my `.htaccess` internally redirect to `/dir/load_page.php` then my `load_page.php` handles everything else. If you want to do it that way I can give you my `.htaccess`, and then the other stuff is somewhat simple php. Otherwise, I can probably write up the rules you need to just rewrite the URL internally with the `.htaccess` but the latter is less robust.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by saying that PHP handles everything else... Let me clarify what I need and if this is what you understand than, I'd be happy to know both ways. So how to get a request for /special/index.php to actually load /special/laravel/public/index.php - yes, but I want the URL in the browser of the client to read /special/index.php

Answer (score 0):

**Simply rewrite the URL with `.htaccess`:** (goes in `/`)

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

#Redirect to /special/laravel/public if you haven't already and the IP is okay
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^1\.2\.3\.4*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/special/laravel/public
RewriteRule ^(/special)(/laravel)?(.+) /special/laravel/public$2 [L]

#if IP does not match and you ARE in the folder, then Redirect to root
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/special/laravel/public
RewriteRule .? / [R=301,L]
```

I think that'll work. I didn't test it though. I can add to it if you need me to. And of course for your use case you may need to add some more `RewriteCond`s in there for validating the `REMOTE_ADDR`.

**The way I handle it:**

.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/load_page.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /load_page.php [QSA, L]
```

That causes the server to redirect internally to `load_page.php` if the requested URL is not `load_page`. Without the RewriteCond, I believe it would cause an infinite redirect. This should work, but I didn't test it because it's different from my implementation, since mine also handles rewriting URLS to have trailing slashes and never show .php which makes it a bit more complex and quite different.

`load_page.php`:

```
$SITE_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$URL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

ob_start();
if (conditionOne){
    //change $URL here if you need to or do nothing
} else if (conditionTwo){ //check the IP or whatever you want to here
    if (aCondition){//if $URL starts with '/special'
        $URL = str_ireplace('/special/','/special/laravel/public/',$URL,1);
    }
    if (is_dir($SITE_ROOT.$URL))$URL .='index.php';
} 
if (!file_exists($SITE_ROOT.$URL))$URL = '/error/404.php';
include($SITE_ROOT.$URL);
$content = ob_get_clean();
echo $content;
```

It's something to that affect. The user doesn't see `load_page.php` and they don't see that you changed the URL to `special/laravel/public`, but you include the correct file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will (on a later stage) definitely implement the PHP version. But for now I got it all twisted with the .htaccess files. So what how I got confused is: I have 3 physical folders /, /special and /special/laravel/public. Which statments in which .htacces file should I put?

Comment: I'm thinking that I need to use Alias in the apache configuration.

Comment: I edited my answer. I would probably only use one `.htaccess` because I personally find that easier to manage. If you need more and you tell me what you want in a fairly plain way like `if (thisConditionIsTrue){do this}else if (thisOtherConditionIsTrue){do that}` then I can try to write up functioning `.htaccess`. But, in my experience, most of the difficulty in htaccess comes from difficulty with regex. If that's your issue, then check out http://www.regexr.com/ otherwise you may need to just read more on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: Also, `Alias` might be a good way to go, but I haven't used it before so I wouldn't be able to help.